# accidentally added large file to git... how to remove?

Tags: git, file, checkout, revert

silly me...

so i as blindly adding files to git with `git add .`, not realising that there were some stupidly large tarballs in the path. and of course not having the relevant `.gitignore` in place.

of course, i didn't think too much of it, and didn't run a `git status` before committing it... and then some other commits too.

so...

```
$ git ls-files | xargs ls -l | sort -nrk5 | head -n 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 ytl sf 3046648860 Oct 18  2018 images/rosetta/rosetta_src_3.10_bundle.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 ytl    sf   160017409 May 15 14:32 images/chimera/1.13.1/chimera-1.13.1-linux_x86_64.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 ytl    sf   4768999 Oct 16  2018 images/protomo/deplibs.tar.bz2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ytl    sf   2662328 Apr 24  2019 images/motioncor2/1.2.3-intpix/MotionCor2
```

and

```
$ git log --pretty="%h - %s"
cbc481c - remove large files
0b3e0d8 - add checks
f318f18 - modify cluster
f44838c - lots of changes...
ac7d198 - pick up parent bin.files
```

`ac7d198` is just before my stupidness. `cbc481c` contains me trying to do `git rm --cached <files>`. of course, when i do a push, it will still try to put the files into git...

so... i know that if i just do a `git checkout`, it will basically remove the files from the file system that were added after that checkout.

so my question is how can i revert everything back to `ac7d198` without loosing any data? or even better, how can i just remove just the large files from the commit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: thanks @phd i ended up using https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo which worked like a charm!